# C# Entity Framework / SQL Server count number of matched data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Given a table Foo:

```
table Foo (
  name,
  city,
  country,
  year,
  color,
  age
);
```

Data that is stored in the Foo table:

```
Peter, Brussels, Belgium, 2013, blue, 19
Dirk, Brussels, Belgium, 1999, red, 33
Jean, Paris, France, 2011, blue, 27
```

Line of data I want to match against database:

```
Peter, Brussels, Belgium, 2013, blue, 19
```

==> should give for:

```
row 1: 100% or 6
row 2: 33% or 2
row 3: 16% or 1
```

Another line of data to test:

```
Peter, Paris, France, 2011, green, 36
```

==> should give for:

```
row 1: 16% or 1
row 2: 0% or 0
row 3: 50% or 3
```

I could fetch all data in memory and run some C# logic on it, but that would not be the smartest thing.

Would it be possible to do this kind of calculation ("% that matches row data") in a single query?

**Bonus:**

Is it possible to add weights to columns so that column 3 and 5 would add a higher count-weight?

Using C# with EF with a code-first approach, and a SQL Server database (stored procedure is not an option as the database could be a different type).

Comment: So... what have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do both requirements that you have listed - only need to write code for it.

Comment: You are looking for `ctx.Foos.Select(c => (c.Name == name ? 1 : 0) + (c.City == city ? 1 : 0) + ...)`

Comment: @JuanR what I've done so far is just fetching all data with a .ToList() and looping over the data, counting manually and in my case keeping only the row with the highest result. (similar as of doing a .Max() on the result).

Via a query on the database via subqueries but don't see a way out.

Comment: @juFo: That's a good start. Please post your code as well so we can help you improve it.

Comment: @JuanR started with this and several attempts, but always got stuck  select f from Foo  select new FooCount  {  ColumnCount1 = (from g in Foo where g.City == "Brussels")}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary conditional operator for each condition which returns 1 or 0, and add each result. You could replace the 1s with other numbers to achieve weighting, in which case the value 6.0 in the percentage calculation should be replaced with the sum of the weight values.

```
 foos.Select(x => 
     (x.name == "Peter" ? 1 : 0) +
     (x.city == "Brussels" ? 1 : 0) +
     (x.country == "Belgium" ? 1 : 0) +
     (x.year == 2013 ? 1 : 0) +
     (x.color == "blue" ? 1 : 0) +
     (x.age == 19 ? 1 : 0))
     .Select(x => $"{Math.Round(x / 6.0 * 100, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}% or {x}");
```

Comment: does this calculate on the database or in memory (e.g. fetching all rows inmemory) ?

Comment: At the database. Each ternary is converted into a sql `CASE WHEN Foo = 'Bar' THEN 1 ELSE 0` operator.